# Creating a sort function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a sort function in R.
I am aware that there is a `sort()` function to make things easy. But I am currently learning R and want to try writing this function which will help me understand  loop,function of R language. Below is what I tried.

I have entered in `x <- c(6,4,2,7)`, and after sorting it should become `x = (2,4,6,7)`

```
myx<-function(x)
for(i in length(x))
 {
   if(x[i]>x[i+1])
    {
      tmp<-x[i]
      x[i]<-x[i+1]
      x[i+1]<-tmp
    } 
  break
 }
```

I know I am bad at programming, but hope to improve it with your help.
Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: What you wrote is one pass of something called bubble sort, which won't always work with just one pass (usually requires three passes). Are you aware of insertion sort, merge sort, or quick sort? Otherwise you can do your current for loop 3 times and it should sort.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of syntax issues with your code. First, you made the common mistake of doing `for (i in length(x))` rather than `for (i in 1:length(x))`; the former evaluates to `for (i in 4)`, whereas you most likely wanted `for (i in 1:4)`. However, since you are calling `x[i + 1]` in your code, you want to modify your loop range to be `for (i in 1:(length(x)-1))`, otherwise you will get an out of bounds error. Also, (generally speaking) objects are not modified by reference in R functions, so you need to return the result,  either implicitly (`x`) or explicitly (`return(x)`) at the end of your function.

On a conceptual level, as pointed out in @johnny838's comment, your algorithm will have to be applied multiple times to get a completely sorted vector. Trying to stick to your above code as closely as possible, here's one way to get it working:

```
myx <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:(length(x) - 1)) {
    if (x[i] > x[i+1]) {
      tmp <- x[i]
      x[i] <- x[i+1]
      x[i+1] <- tmp
    }
  }
  x
}
##
sortx <- function(x) {
  while (is.unsorted(x)) {
    x <- myx(x)
  }
  x
}
##
R> x
#[1] 6 4 2 7
R> sortx(x)
#[1] 2 4 6 7
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer probably worthy of being accepted.